# CSS / Bootstrap - font-size not properly resizing from computer to mobile device: Font on Mobile device looks so small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

This is my CSS:

```
@media(max-width:767px){body { font-size: 22px; }}
@media(min-width:768px){body { font-size: 20px; }}
@media(min-width:992px){body { font-size: 16px; }}
```

When I resize my browser window on my laptop, it properly resizes. But this is my issue: When I visit my website from my mobile device, the font-size is way too small (I'm not sure why but 22px on my mobile device is so small that I have to zoom in in order to see it properly). When I increase the font-size for smaller screen width's to 40px, it looks good on my mobile device, but when I go and visit the website from my laptop and resize my browser window to a smaller width, 40px is way too big and ends up taking over the entire screen.

22px on my mobile device looks so small. Is there a way (with Bootstrap or  pure CSS) for me to fix this issue? By issue, I mean, 22px is too small but 40px is perfect on my mobile device. However, it's the exact opposite (22px is perfect but 40px is way too big) on my computer.

Comment: Did you try setting the `viewport`? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: @kittykittybangbang oh dear, turns out that my code on production did not have the viewport set. (I even Google'd around and saw answers on SO which mentioned to make sure the viewport is set. At the time, I assumed that my code on production had it since my development code had it. I checked it again after your comment and turns out my production code didn't have the viewport set -.-. Anyways, the viewport solved the issue, so thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and added as an answer so that this question can be 'answered.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try setting the viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics

Comment: Most common mistake to make. I've done it several times.